# two functions are not calling synchronously on typeahead-on-select()

Tags: angularjs

There are three functions in my directive:-

```
scope.fetchDetails = function(){
        scope.a.data1 = scope.margin1;
        scope.a.data2 = scope.margin2;
       scope.getMargin(scope.a.data1,scope.a.data2);             
   }

    scope.getMargin = function(data1,data2 {
        ApiServices.getMargin(data1,data2).then(function (response) {
            scope.selected = response.data;
            scope.a.allValues = scope.selected.Values;
        });
    }

    scope.getUser = function(){
        if(!scope.a.allValues){
            scope.a.allValues = "NULL";
        }     
            ApiServices.getUser(scope.a.allValues).then(function (response){
                 scope.user= response.data;
            });
    }
```

I am calling this function in my textbox:-

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="a.prod" typeahead="s for s in prods | filter:$viewValue" typeahead-on-select="fetchDetails();getUser()"/>
```

What I want is first to call `fetchDetails` which will give me allValues and then it calls `getUser` which gives me rest of data.
    But its calling `getUser` first and `fetchDetails` after that, which is why I am not able to fetch data.If I run that code again for different `scope.a.allValues`. It is calling for previous `scope.a.allValues`.
    Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: try this, call getUser() in fetchDetails() after scope.getMargin() I think it should work

Answer (score 0):

It actually first calls fetchDetails and then getUser, but since they're asynchronous, getUser may finish before fetchDetails and vice versa.

To make them execute and finish in sequence, you need to chain your promises, so when fetchDetails() resolves, it calls getUser().

To do that you'd have to change your code to something this:

```
scope.fetchDetails = function(){
    scope.a.data1 = scope.margin1;
    scope.a.data2 = scope.margin2;
    return scope.getMargin(scope.a.data1,scope.a.data2)
        .then(scope.getUser);     
}

scope.getMargin = function(data1,data2) {
    return ApiServices.getMargin(data1,data2).then(function (response) {
        scope.selected = response.data;
        scope.a.allValues = scope.selected.Values;
    });
}

scope.getUser = function(){
    if(!scope.a.allValues){
        scope.a.allValues = "NULL";
    }     
    return ApiServices.getUser(scope.a.allValues).then(function (response){
        scope.user = response.data;
    });
}
```

Then in your view, you only call `fetchDetails()`:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="a.prod" typeahead="s for s in prods | filter:$viewValue" typeahead-on-select="fetchDetails()"/>
```